# Append correlation id to every log java

Tags: java, multithreading, slf4j, mdc

I need to append correlation id to logs from every request I get.

Here is my filter. It works good until I get to async block like `runAsync()`.

[image: logs]

I read about MDC and how it use ThreadLocal but can't understand how to use it in async because it uses ForkJoinPool.

```
@Component
public class Slf4jFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final String CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME = "correlation-id";
private static final String CORRELATION_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME = "correlationId";

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        ofNullable(request.getHeader(CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME)).ifPresent(correlationId -> MDC
            .put(CORRELATION_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME, correlationId));
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }finally {
        removeCorrelationId();
    }
}

protected void removeCorrelationId() {
    MDC.remove(CORRELATION_ID_LOG_VAR_NAME);
}
}
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration>
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread %X{correlationId}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
</root>
```

Comment: Same thing you do in filters - you should do when submitting the task for processing. The task will capture info from MDC where it was created, and set it up when it starts, then tears it down when it is finished.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't understand little bit, what task you are talking about. I call my controller method, then it goes to service method where I use `runAsync()`. And I don't pass correlation id anywhere(you can answer in russian)

Comment: This is not a russian SO is the thing - so I can't. Generally speaking, whatever the `runAsync` is, should pass MDC context (or part of it) to the worker thread. The task here is any `Callable` or `Runnable` that worker pool executes. Without seeing what `runAsync` is, I can't really say any further.

Comment: `runAsync(new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(() -> {
            method1();
            method2();
        }, SecurityContextHolder.getContext()));`

Comment: Hm. So, the `DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable` in this case (I assume it's from Spring? they like these sorts of names) already does what I'm talking about, but with Spring's security context. Look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/concurrent/DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable.java), see how it sets a thing into `SecurityContextHolder`? That holder is also a house for a thread local, similar to MDC. You will need another wrapper (or subclass this `Runnable`) which will pass MDC values.

Comment: I'll add this as an answer later.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up. Thanks to @M.Prokhorov

Create a class called `MdcRetention` inside your project.

```
public final class MdcRetention {

public static Runnable wrap(final Runnable delegate) {
    return new MdcRetainingRunnable() {
        @Override
        protected void runInContext() {
            delegate.run();
        }
    };
}

private static abstract class MdcRetentionSupport {
    protected final Map<String, String> originalMdc;

    protected MdcRetentionSupport() {
        Map<String, String> originalMdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        this.originalMdc = originalMdc == null ? Collections.emptyMap() : originalMdc;
    }
}

public static abstract class MdcRetainingRunnable extends MdcRetentionSupport implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        Map<String, String> currentMdc = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        MDC.setContextMap(originalMdc);
        try {
            runInContext();
        } finally {
            MDC.setContextMap(currentMdc);
        }
    }

    abstract protected void runInContext();
}}
```

Then wrap your Runnable inside `runAsync()` block using static method `MdcRetention.wrap()`

Before:
`runAsync(() -> someMethod());`

After:
`runAsync(wrap(() -> someMethod()));`